# intel-pin: How to pass command line arguments to binary

Tags: c++, c, reverse-engineering, intel-pin

I have a simple c code. I am running the binary of that with my pin tool:

```
pin -t tool.so -- test/test.o a
```

Here, `test/test.o` is a binary, and `a` is some random command line argument to the pin tool (say `tool.so`), and not the binary (so, there is a distinction between passing command line argument to the pin tool and to the binary).

I would like to know how can I pass command line input (say `arg1`) to the binary which I am running with the pin tool.

(like we would pass with - `./test/test.o arg1`)

Note: I think knowing my pin tool and the c code is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe here will pass command line arguments to the program you're running. Command line arguments to the tool are all the arguments that come after the -t argument and before the -- (double dash) which indicates the binary and its arguments